# proof of continuity of coordinate functions (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

[image]
[image]

I find a hard time understanding the above example of continuity of coordinate functions. What I understood from the example is that a coordinate function takes a point in $R^k$ and gives a real number; how is that gonna be continuous on $R^k$. May someone explain please?

Comment: If $|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|<\varepsilon$, then also $|\phi_i(\mathbf{x})-\phi_i(\mathbf{y})|<\varepsilon$. What's unclear?

Comment: @egreg how is that number continuous intuitively? And is $y$ a different point than $x$? and how we choose $\delta=\epsilon$?

Comment: "how is that number continuous?" the number is not continuous, that doesn't mean anything. The function is continuous. Yes $y$ is different than $x$, if it is the same the claim is certainly true. See the argument below for why $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: Apply the definition with $p=\mathbb{y}$.

Comment: @qbert  If, for example, we take $x=(1,1) \in R^2 $ Is $\phi_1(x)=1$? If yes, should I understand that $\phi_1(x)$ is a constant function in $R^1$? I'm sorry, but I really don't understand!

Comment: if you pick a point and evaluate *any* function, you get a number, this is true. But that definitely does not mean you have a constant function.

Comment: @qbert So, $\phi_1(x)$ is just an isolated point in $R^2$, right? in my example, it's just the point $(1,0)$, right?

Comment: @AbduMagdy The range of $\phi_i$ is $\mathbb{R}$ for any $i$. If $x=(a,b,c)$, then $\phi_1(x) = a$ and $\phi_2(x) = b$ and $\phi_3(x) = c$, so how can $\phi_1(x)$ be a point in $\mathbb{R^2}?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\phi_i$ just picks out the coordinate $x_i$.

It's just the statement that if distance between two vectors goes to $0$, then the distance between each of their coordinates also goes to $0$.

If you want, you could use the definition of the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then plug in what everything is:

$$ |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}| = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + ... + (x_n-y_n)^2 } $$ so

$$|\phi_i(\mathbf{x}) - \phi_i(\mathbf{y})| = |x_i - y_i|= \sqrt{(x_i-y_i)^2}$$

As you can see, just as Rudin says, $$|\phi_i(\mathbf{x}) - \phi_i(\mathbf{y})| \leq |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|$$

And so, given $\epsilon$, put $\delta = \epsilon$, if $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|< \delta$, then $|\phi_i(\mathbf{x}) - \phi_i(\mathbf{y})| < \epsilon$

Comment: Really thanks for your answer and your reply above :). So, we are talking about something like a vector valued function and $\phi_1$ for instance traces the values of the first coordinate through out the domain. Is that a right imagination?

Comment: Almost, usually, "vector-valued" means that the range is multidimensional. Here, the range is one-dimensional, and the domain is multi-dimensional. Otherwise, it sounds good.

Comment: Now I understand the concept; really  thank you for your explanation and patience :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of continuity is the same as the one you are used to for single variate functions. If you want to keep distances in the range smaller than say $\epsilon>0$, then you can find a suitably small $\delta>0$ ball in the domain for which inputs in this ball map to outputs inside the $\epsilon>0$ ball.

Try it with a two variable example: If 
$$
\phi_1(x,y)=x
$$
Then insuring $|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|\leq \delta$ (the 1 norm in the *domain*, norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent), then 
$$
|\phi_1(x,y)-\phi(x_0,y_0)|=|x-x_0|\leq \delta
$$
the norm in the *range* being used above.
So indeed, choosing $\delta=\epsilon$ meets any $\epsilon>0$ challenge.